# Pass a parameter into a function and use it to reference a property

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

Is it possible to pass a parameter to a function and use it somehow to reference a property of an object:

For example (doesn't seem to work):

```
function Some-Function ($objectarray, $parameter)
{
    $result = $objectarray | ?{$_.$parameter -eq $true}
}
```

This seems to work fine with for exanple:

```
function Some-Function ($objectarray, $parameter)
{
    $result = $objectarray | Select Name, $parameter
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the object property by name. You are almost there, you just need to return the result to make it working, for example:

```
function Some-Function ($objectarray, $parameter)
{
   $objectarray | ?{$_.$parameter -eq $false}
}

Some-Function (Get-Process) Responding
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the problem was using .Count when I was returning a single object, just noticed that now.

Comment: In fact you were not returning an object. You were just capturing the result.

Answer (score 0):

[Reza Aghaei's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47851759/45375) makes an important point: your original function was missing an *output-generating* statement.

Additionally, in PSv3+, you can simplify the function using a *comparison statement* and *implicit* Boolean logic:

```
function Some-Function ($objectarray, $property) {
  # short for: ? { $_.$property } or ? { $_.$property -eq $true }
  $objectArray | ? $property
}
```

---

In a comment you state:

> the problem was using .Count when I was returning a single object

This should only ever be a problem in *PSv2*.
In *PSv3+*, *any* value, whether a scalar or collection - even `$null` - *should* have a `.Count` property.

- Unfortunately, as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.0.0-rc.2, that is *not* yet true of *all* types: see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3671